# Find the jump of force of mortality under Balducci assumption

Tags: probability, limits, solution-verification, actuarial-science, continuity

I need to find the jump of $\mu_x$  (force of mortality) under Balducci assumption at the point n $\in \Bbb N$. 
Under the assumption of Baoducci  force of mortality function has the form:
$$\mu_{x}= \frac{q_n} {(p_n + (x-n)q_n)},  x \in (n, n+1)$$ where $q_n$  is the probability of death between the ages of $x$ and age $x + 1$ and  $p_n$ is the probability that a life age  $x$ will survive to age $x + 1$.
 It is also known that: $$p_n = \frac{s(n+1)} {s(n)} \\ q_n = 1- p_n$$
I found the left and right limits:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to n+0} \mu_x = \frac{q_n}{p_n}$$ and 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to n-0} \mu_x = \frac{q_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}}$$
So jump will be $$\Delta = \frac{q_n}{p_n}- \frac{q_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}}=\frac{1-p_n}{p_n}- q_{n-1}=
\frac{1}{p_n}- q_{n-1}$$$$$$And then I don't know if I can leave the answer in this form or whether it is still necessary to simplify. I tried to simplify the expression but it turned out only more complicated. And I doubt if I did everything right. I would be grateful for  any advice.

Comment: Are you sure your conclusion for $\lim\limits_{x \to n-0} \mu_x$ is right?  If $x = n-\epsilon$ then $\mu_{x}= \frac{q_{n-1}} {(p_{n-1} + (x-(n-1))q_{n-1})} = \frac{q_{n-1}} {(p_{n-1} + (1-\epsilon))q_{n-1})}$ which tends to something with $p_{n-1} + q_{n-1}$ in the denominator

Comment: @MilesB  $\mu_{x}= \frac{q_n} {(p_n + (x-n)q_n)},  x \in (n, n+1)$, but $ x = n-\epsilon  \in \not (n, n+1) $ so  $\mu_{x}= \frac{q_n-1} {(p_n-1 + (x-n+1)q_n-1)}   x \in (n-1, n)$

Comment: Ah yes, but $\mu_{x}= \frac{q_{n-1}} {(p_{n-1} + (x-(n-1))q_{n-1})}, x\in (n-1,n)$ and $n-\epsilon \in (n-1,n)$

Comment: @MilesB Fixed the main question. Thanks a lot !

Comment: OK. Your very last step looks wrong.  I can't see how the answer can be any simpler than $\frac{q_n}{p_n}- q_{n-1}$.  Ah, this takes me back - qualified as an actuary over 15 years ago and haven't seen much of this since.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer looks fine until right at the end, where I would say:
$\Delta = \frac{q_n}{p_n}- \frac{q_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}}=\frac{q_n}{p_n}- q_{n-1}$